# Android: RadioGroup - Listening For Click Event

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, radio-group

I have a customized `RadioGroup` and like to execute some code when one off the buttons is clicked regardless if it did change the state or not. The `onCheckedChanged` Event is only triggered when a new selection is done and the `onClick` events seems never to be triggered. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I set the onClickListener for the Radio Group but it seems it never gets triggered. That is exactly my issue.

Comment: Don't know perfect solution or not, but this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = radioGroup.getChildCount();
for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    View o = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
    if (o instanceof RadioButton) {
        o.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As you have said it does not look perfect but it is doing what I'm looking for.